# process cvs data for d3

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

So as I was doing a D3 tutorial, creating a bubblechart with a world population in csv file format, the radius for the circles cannot be read.

```
    var circles = svg.selectAll(".country")
      .data(datapoints)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class","country")
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        return radiusScale(d.ranking)
    })
```

the browser returns 
Error:  attribute r: Expected length, "NaN".

My csv file looks like this
[world-population.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqxSN.png)

Thank you all very much !

Comment: hard to say without seeing a full example. 
just a guess - try `d.Ranking`

Comment: https://data.worldbank.org/data-catalog/Population-ranking-table
I tried d.Ranking and it was still the same error :/

Comment: In your browser's console try running `console.log(datapoints[0])` to see the first object in your data. If it is an object that includes a key of ranking, try running `radiusScale(datapoints[0].ranking)`. What results do you get?

Comment: it says datapoints not defined ...
but I have
    function ready (error, datapoints) {
wrapping outside of var circles

Comment: Try adding those `console.log` lines to your code just above where you call `var circles = svg...` and see what your console returns.

Comment: oh yes then that worked ! I can see the object. Then I `.attr("r", function(d) {
          return radiusScale(datapoints[0].Ranking)
        })`
which worked (didn't return any error) but I dont understand how d and datapoints are related ? and how do I iterate through the whole list ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how the top lines in the CSV  look like:

```
,Population 2016,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,
,Ranking,,Economy,(thousands),,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,
CHN,1,,China,"1,378,665",,,,,,,
```

Try changing it to:

```
CountryCode,Ranking,,CountryName,Count
CHN,1,,China,"1,378,665",,,,,,,
```